# Cypher query to compare two dates

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query to compare two dates.But it getting error.What is wrong with this query? Can any one help please?

```
GraphClient client= new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/"));
                              client.Connect();  
                              var date=client.Cypher
                              .Match("(e2:Event)")
                              .Where((Event e2) => Convert.ToDateTime(e2.notificationTime).CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0 )
                                .return(e=>e.As<Event>()).Results;
```

error:

```
SyntaxException: Invalid input '{': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '?', '!', '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR or ')' (line 25, column 25)"AND (e2.notificationTime{p7} < {p8})
```

Comment: It seems to be something with your input that doesn't fit - can you tell us what e2 is and what e is?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change "AndWhere" part to "Where" because you don't need chaining 'where' clause in that code. Maybe it is the reason that it cant be translated into cypher.

If it still wont work, then i'd say that issue is inside your 'Where' clause. Its possible that Convert.ToDateTime().CompareTo cannot be translated to cypher. You should try to simplify your code then. It depends on what type is your e2.notificationTime. 
For instanse, if its in Unix format:

```
var currentDate = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
GraphClient client= new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/"));
client.Connect();  
var date=client.Cypher
               .Match("(e2:Event)")
               .Where((Event e2) => e2.notificationTime < currentDate)
               .Return(e=>e.As<Event>()).Results;
```

You have to get rid of any complex expressions inside 'where' clause because it is translating into cypher

Comment: Sorry.That is my mistake while updating the query for post question.The error is not about that.

Comment: But e2.notificationTime is in 'Friday, August 08, 2014 9:45:00 AM' format